# What external battery do I need?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, servo, battery

For a school project I need to connect an Arduino with an accelerometer gyroscope sensor and 2 mini servo motors. Of course I need a battery for this. However, I don’t know what battery I need for this. I have no clue where to start. Does anyone know which battery I can use? Or how I can find this out? I added links of the sensor, Arduino and servo motors that I have below.

Thanks in advance! :)

Sensor:
https://www.tinytronics.nl/shop/nl/sensoren/acceleratie-rotatie/mpu-6500-accelerometer-gyroscope-6dof-module-3.3v-5v

Arduino uno:
https://www.tinytronics.nl/shop/nl/development-boards/microcontroller-boards/arduino-compatible/uno-r3-met-usb-kabel

Mini servo motor:
https://www.tinytronics.nl/shop/nl/mechanica-en-actuatoren/motoren/servomotoren/ts90d-mini-servo-1.6kg-continuous

Comment: Before you can select a battery, you have to find out how much current your setup uses. You could do this by connecting everything up to a power supply, running the code you intend to run on batteries and measuring the (average) current from the power supply with a multimeter. You also have to figure out how long you need your battery to last as this will determine the minimum capacity you need. You need to take into account voltage conversion (for example for converting the output of a 3.7V LiPo to the 5V needed by the Arduino).

Comment: If you don't want to build your own battery system, you could probably just use a common 5V power bank (i.e. the type used for charging your phone on the road) with sufficient capacity.

Comment: Unless you want to make the battery part of your learning experience I second StarCats suggestion of the USB power bank. It is the easiest way to add a battery. I often use them in my projects. Though this can also depend on the exact power bank. Often the bigger ones automatically turn off, when not enough current is drawn. Havent seen that with cheap little power banks (which might be enough for you)

Comment: @chrisl There is [kind a remedy](https://youtu.be/lOL3ic8msas?t=586) for these auto turn-off power banks, designed by Mr Carlson

Comment: Hi Thank you for answering! Sadly I do not have a multimeter of anything like that. I am really not familiar with things like this to be honest… So what battery should I use now then? …

Comment: given the constraints of usb power bank, and an unknown amp hour need and no ability to figure it out, go with the highest amp hour usb power bank you can use and hope it's enough.

Comment: If you can't figure the requirements out you are only left with trail and error. I would think any USB power bank can provide enough current for your project. Then choose a power bank with an amp hour rating of your liking (that sets the run time with the fully charged power bank